# Referencing and manipulating data frame in foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

```
for(artist in 1:nrow(epop8)){
  message(paste("Artist:", artist))
  id = epop8$spotify_id[artist];
  cur_showDate = epop8$ShowDate[artist]
  dma_show = epop8$DMA_Region_Code[artist]
  spotifySubset = na.omit(spotify[spotify$spotify_id == id,])

  if(nrow(spotifySubset) == 0){
    epop8$last6month[artist] = NA
    next
  }
  monthsOfInterest_6 = epop8$ShowDate[artist] - 180:1
  monthsOfInterest_12 = epop8$ShowDate[artist] - 365:1

  epop8Subset6MO = unique(epop8[epop8$ShowDate %in% monthsOfInterest_6,
                                c("spotify_id", "DMA_Region_Code", "ShowDate")]) %>%
    subset(., DMA_Region_Code == dma_show) %>% arrange(desc(ShowDate))

  epop8Subset1Yr = unique(epop8[epop8$ShowDate %in% monthsOfInterest_12,
                                c("spotify_id", "DMA_Region_Code", "ShowDate")]) %>%
    subset(., DMA_Region_Code == dma_show) %>% arrange(desc(ShowDate))

  last6month = epop8Subset6MO[spotifySubset$relatedID %in% epop8Subset6MO$spotify_id,] 
  last12month = epop8Subset1Yr[spotifySubset$relatedID %in% epop8Subset1Yr$spotify_id,]

  epop8$since_related_artist[artist] = ifelse(!nrow(last6month) && !nrow(last12month),
                                              365,
                                              as.double(cur_showDate - last6month$ShowDate[1]))
  epop8$related_artist_count_6MO[artist] = nrow(last6month)
  epop8$related_artist_count_12MO[artist] = nrow(last12month)
}
```

I am simply trying to "convert" this for loop into a parallelized foreach loop. I've tried to comprehend how to even approach the foreach loop. I've tried

```
ntasks <- nrow(epop8)
pb <- tkProgressBar(max=nrow(epop8))
progress <- function(n) setTkProgressBar(pb, n)
opts <- list(progress=progress)

foreach(artist=1:nrow(epop8), .combine = combine,
        .packages = "dplyr", .options.snow=opts) %dopar%{
...
}
```

Where "..." is the exact same code that is contained within my for loop above. Now, I know this isn't the way to do it necessarily but I'm not sure how to update my dataframe or subset my dataframe at all within a foreach parallelized loop. I've scoured the internet but I'm beginning to think that foreach is a little over my head.

- We have two dataframes, epop8 and spotify. epop8 is a dataframe full
  of receipts from shows around the US and spotify is spotify data for
  each artist in epop8.
- This code establishes a unique id, a show date, a DMA (region), and a
  list of related musical artist IDs to the unique id (spotifySubset).
- It then establishes an array of dates in the last 6 months and then
  an array of dates in the last 12 months to compare to.
- The full dataset of shows is then subsetted down to all shows in the
  last 6 months and all shows in the last 12 months within the
  specified region.
- These two subsets are then subsetted once again to just include
  related artists (as determined by spotify) and produces metrics based
  on the last6month and last12month data frames.
- Using those two dataframes I write results to the original epop8
  dataframe for the current artist.

Here is what the datasets look like:

```
spotify = data.frame(artistName = "Bob", spotify_id = "abcd", 
                     related = c("Al", "Bill", "Charles","Daniel"),
                  relatedID = c("1234", "efrd", "bcde", "fghi"))
epop8 = data.frame(id = c("abcd", "asdf", "robd", "1234"), 
                      dma = c("654", "332", "489", "654"),
                      ShowDate = c("2017-10-08", "2011-10-04", "2012-10-01", "2017-08-01"))
```

So here, when we subset epop8 for the last 6 months and 12 months in the DMA for Bob (the first artist in epop8), we get that there is one match for a show in that DMA in the last 12 months -- Daniel on 2017-08-01.

Hopefully this all makes sense, I'd really love your help on this one!

Comment: Maybe [this blog post](https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/) could help you understand more about foreach-parallel.

Comment: Will give this post a read, thank you.